# memory allocation about char *buffer and char buffer[5]

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory, stack

I want to ask about a memory allocation question about char *buffer; buffer = malloc(5); and char buffer[5].

My code for test is below:]

```
#include <stdio.h>
void echo1();
void echo2();

int main() {
    echo1();
    printf("\n");
    echo2();
    printf("Back to Main \n");
    return 0;
}

void echo1() {
    int i;
    unsigned long addr;
    char *buffer;
    printf("[Echo1] Buffer      : %p \n", buffer);
    printf("[Echo1] &Buffer     : %p \n", &buffer);
    buffer = malloc(5);
    printf("[Echo1] &Buffer     : %p \n", &buffer);
    printf("[Echo1] Buffer      : %p \n", buffer);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        buffer[i] = 'A';
    }
    printf("[Echo1] Buffer[]    : %s \n", buffer); 
    addr = &buffer;
    printf("[Echo1] *Buffer     : %p \n", *buffer); 
    printf("[Echo1] addr        : %p \n", addr); 
    printf("[Echo1] &addr       : %p \n", &addr); 
}

void echo2() {
    int i;
    unsigned long addr;
    char buffer[5];
    printf("[Echo2] Buffer      : %p \n", buffer);
    printf("[Echo2] &Buffer     : %p \n", &buffer);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        buffer[i] = 'A';
    }
    printf("[Echo2] Buffer[]    : %s \n", buffer); 
    addr = &buffer;
    printf("[Echo2] *Buffer     : %p \n", *buffer); 
    printf("[Echo2] addr        : %p \n", addr); 
    printf("[Echo2] &addr       : %p \n", &addr); 
}
```

I compiled it on ubuntu by typing gcc test.c -o test -m32 (I'm using a 64 machine). And the following figure shows the result.
[image]

I think I understand the echo1() case (except for why addr is above buffer), and made a figure to show what happened in the memory.
[image]

But I have no idea what happened in echo2() case.

So I want to ask the following questions:

1. In echo1(), I declared addr before  buffer, why addr is placed above buffer in stack? (since stack moves upward, shouldn't the program firstly push addr and then push buffer above it?)
2. In echo2(), why buffer and &buffer give the same value? Doesn't this mean buffer is pointing to itself?
3. In echo2(), addr's address and addr's content(address of buffer) is separated by 12 bytes, what is stored in them?
4. Can anyone make a figure to help me understanding what happened in ehco2()?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you printf with `%s`, the argument must be a null-terminated string. You never added a null byte to the `buffer`.

Comment: I was trying to cause a buffer overflow... And I also don't know why the program correctly output AAAAA and nothing else... Shouldn't some other characters be output since I didn't add a null at the end?

Comment: Just because you didn't add it doesn't mean there isn't one there. You got lucky.

Comment: Local variables aren't pushed one at a time on the stack. When a function is called, space is allocated on the stack for all the local variables. The locations of each variable within the stack frame are arbitrary. The compiler may rearrange them to minimize wasted space between variables, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

> Why the same?

The address of an array on the stack and the address of it's first element is the same. The difference would be incrementing the resulting pointers because they have different sizes.

> What's in between?

The address of a pointer is a stack address while the address returned by `malloc()` and stored in the pointer is from the heap.

Note: Your code also exhibits many sources of undefined behavior, for example

- Printing `*Buffer` with the `"%p"` specifier.
- Printing uninitialized pointers.
- Printing `unsigned long addr` uninitialized and with the `"%p"` specifier, both of which invoke undefined behavior.
- Printing a non-`null` terminated array with the `"%s"` specifier.

So you can't expect a given behavior in `echo2()` and in general in the whole program.

Comment: I think the gist of the question is about the ordering and spacing of the addresses of stack variables.  The UB could all be fixed up and the same question would remain.

Comment: @M.M Maybe you are right but still I think ok to point out *these issues* and it of course can't be done in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone make a figure to help me understanding what happened in 
>      ehco2()?

The best answer for this entire problem is to use gcc's -O0 flag to produce un-optimized code, and either run it in a debugger or also use the -S to review the assembly that corresponds to the code it is producing.

> 1. In echo1(), I declared addr before buffer, why addr is placed above buffer in stack? (since stack moves upward, shouldn't the
>      program firstly push addr and then push buffer above it?)

But you didn't assign a value to addr until after you assigned one to buffer, so the compiler doesn't have to allocate memory for it until later.

See iharob's good answer for some other points.

Answer (score 1):

> In echo1(), I declared addr before buffer, why addr is placed above buffer in stack?

Because the compiler doesn't have to put automatic variables onto the stack in the order in which they're declared, and, apparently, chose not to.  (In fact, it doesn't have to put them onto the stack *at all* - it could put them in registers if they fit in a register.)

> In echo2(), why buffer and &buffer give the same value? Doesn't this mean buffer is pointing to itself?

It means that `buffer` is an array and, in most contexts, an expression `buffer` evaluates to a pointer to the first element of `buffer`, i.e. it evaluates to `&buffer[0]`, and '&buffer` evaluates to a pointer to the array - but the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array.

`buffer` and `&buffer` have different data types, however ("pointer to `char`" vs. "pointer to array of 5 `char`s").

> In echo2(), addr's address and addr's content(address of buffer) is separated by 12 bytes, what is stored in them?

Whatever the compiler decided to put there in the stack frame.  The layout of a stack frame is not under the direct control of a C (or C++) programmer.  Perhaps the compiler decided to make the address *following* the array be in a 4-byte boundary, rather than putting the first element on a 4-byte boundary.  Perhaps, as you weren't compiling with optimization turned on, it didn't put `i` into a register, but put it on the stack.

C is not a programming language that specifies a strict mapping between automatic variables and locations on the stack; the compiler is free to put variables wherever it chooses (including, as I said above, into registers if that's possible).